# Adding inline to extern "C" function causes linker error when calling from inline assembly

Tags: c++, linker, language-lawyer

I have an `extern "C"` function that is supposed to be called from inline assembly but I noticed that when trying to add `inline` to it (to keep the definition in header file) it causes linker errors.
For example, this causes "undefined reference to `f'" (both gcc and clang):

```
extern "C" inline void f()
{

}

void  __attribute__((naked)) naked_function()
{
    asm volatile("call f");
}

int main()
{
    naked_function();
}
```

Link to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/b8j7TxcPK).

Removing `inline` will make it work, but I am wondering why it happens.

Comment: You're in the realm of implementation-defined behaviour as soon as you use `asm`.    When a function is inlined, the compiler is permitted to substitute its code at the call point without actually emitting separate code for the function definition to an object file - which means the linker cannot find it to link to the `asm volatile("call f")`.   It looks like both gcc and clang do that (at least, with your build options) and, when you omit the `inline` keyword, they emit the function code separately to the object file, so the linker can find it.

Comment: @Peter that makes perfect sense. I know the question has tag language lawyer but if you make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged this `language-lawyer`:

According to the C++ standard your program is ill-formed, because `asm volatile("call f");` is not valid syntax. A conforming compiler must emit a diagnostic for that.

Not only is the meaning of an `asm` statement completely implementation-defined, but the only syntax valid according to the standard is `asm(/*tokens*/);`, optionally prefixed with an attribute sequence.

Also, because you use an identifier containing double underscores the program is IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required) as these identifiers are reserved in all scopes. Technically this has precedent over the ill-formedness that requires a diagnostic, so a compiler does not need to provide a diagnostic for your program as long as the use of `__attribute__` is in there to be conforming.

Obviously both syntax constructs are however intended by the compiler writer for use. What the meaning is supposed to be would be completely up to the compiler. There is no standard/specification governing this. It is reasonable to expect that the compiler will not keep track of specific function calls in an `asm` statement and therefore will not take these calls into account when deciding which functions need to be instantiated and emitted.

Also, `extern "C" inline`, while valid in C++, probably isn't a good idea when actually interfacing with C, because C++ and C standardized on different meanings for `inline`. I wouldn't expect this to work reliably as intended, even with normal calls to the function.

Comment: thanks for the answer. One question, is it really UB if a program uses __attribute__((naked)) which is a compiler extension? Are these kind of identifiers reserved for things like this too?

Comment: @mateeeeeee Yes, the rule says "_are reserved [...] and shall not be used otherwise; no diagnostic required_" (see https://eel.is/c++draft/lex#name-3), i.e. it makes the program IFNDR, effectively equivalent to UB. But in either case, this just means that the standard doesn't place any requirement on the compilers behavior. If the compiler decides to give a program using such an identifier a well-defined meaning, then that's conforming to the standard and obviously ok for the user to use and that's also (partially) the intention behind IFNDR/UB.

Comment: @mateeeeeee   As this answer says identifiers with double underscores are reserved for use by the implementation, and code which uses them has undefined behaviour *according to the C++ standard*.  Now, yes, an implementation (compiler/library/etc) can define an extended meaning for such identifiers, and allow programmers to use those extensions (with the caveat of accepting lock-in to using only implementations that support the same extensions). But "a meaning is defined by an implementation" does not override the fact of "undefined by the standard".